# Does concurrently filing for I-140 and I-485 speed up the green card obtention?

Tags: usa, greencard

I wonder whether concurrently filing for I-140 (Immigrant Petition for Alien Worker) and I-485 (Application to Register Permanent Residence or Adjust Status) speeds up the green card obtention, compared to filing for I-140, then once approved, filing for I-485.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. With concurrent filing both applications are processed together. Once I-140 is approved, the I-485 is probably halfway through processing. If you don't do concurrent filing, you'll need to wait for I-140 approval before filing I-485.

IIRC concurrent filing is also cheaper.